# Getting page_tab_url

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I need to get "page_tab_url" by fql query.
In this article: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/application/
they say, that I need "app access_token" but there is nothing that sticks to the topic on link destination.
Anybody have an idea, what is a name of permission, that I need to use in "scope"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the [correct link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) (for now) that they wanted to link. This is a way to get an access token that authenticate as your application with the appid and secret, you don't need extended permission for that.

here's a small php snippet to illustrate:

```
$appid = '';
$secret = '';

$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token';
$params = array(
    'client_id'     => $appid,
    'client_secret' => $secret,
    'grant_type'    => 'client_credentials',
);

$resp = file_get_contents($url.'?'.http_build_query($params));
$parsed_resp = array();
parse_str($resp, $parsed_resp);

$app_access_token = $parsed_resp['access_token'];
$resp = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20page_tab_url%20from%20application%20where%20app_id={$appid}&access_token={$app_access_token}");

var_dump(json_decode($resp, true));
```

with the `$appid` and `$secret` variables filled with real data, it produces this output:

```
array(1) {
  'data' =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    array(1) {
      'page_tab_url' =>
      string(30) "http://.../"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite shure, that the way You have proposed is enought. I have tried to use: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and used query: SELECT page_tab_url FROM application WHERE app_id = xxxxxxxx with all available permissions submited and access_token regenerated - and still I cant get info about page_tab_url :(

Comment: Thanks for answer - it did helped a lot. Still, just dont get it... why access_token needs to be obtained in this strange way... Why `$facebook->getAccessToken();` cant be used to get correct access token?

Comment: Generally because its a different kind of access token, facebook has 3 of them: user/page/app. And the SDK doesn't have built in "auth as app please" function. However you can create an sdk instance, obtain the app access_token, and use `setAccessToken()` and continue to use the sdk instance as before.

Comment: Ok, that is a hell of reply :). Thanks so much for help.